# Custom SQL query without Corresponding Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a SQL query that isn't table-specific and I don't know how to handle it with Ruby On Rails.

Here my SQL query (you don't need to understand it):

```
SELECT type, actor_id, events.created_at, photo_id, photos.user_id FROM 
(SELECT 'comment' AS type, user_id AS actor_id, created_at, photo_id FROM comments
UNION
SELECT 'classification' AS type, user_id AS actor_id, created_at, photo_id FROM classifications) 
AS events
INNER JOIN photos ON photo_id = photos.id
WHERE user_id = #{@user.id}
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT 9
```

I tried to create a model and use a find_by_sql:

```
class RecentActivity ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :type, :actor_id, :created_at, :photo_id, :user_id
end
```

I get:

```
Mysql::Error: Table 'mysite_development.recent_activities' doesn't exist: SHOW FIELDS FROM `recent_activities`
```

How can I avoid this message? Is there any alternative solution?

Comment: What do you mean, "not table-specific?" I see tables in that query.

Comment: There isn't any MySql table which is named recent_activities  and corresponds to the model.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can grab a db connection directly from ActiveRecord::Base, but it's not as useful as extending AR::Base, because helpful methods like sanitize_sql are protected.

```
class ComplexQueries < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.my_query
    # Notice how you can, and should, still sanitize params here. 
    self.connection.execute(sanitize_sql(["select * from foo limit ?", 10]))
  end
end

results = ComplexQueries.my_query
results.each_hash{|h| puts h.inspect}
```

Comment: Me too! Actually, the only weirdness here is with the last row - you'll likely want to do: results.each_hash{|h| print "#{h}\n" }

On my query, .inspect showed nothing.

Comment: If h has data in it then printing it or printing the results of h.inspect would both work. Did you forget the "puts" in front of h.inspect?

Comment: That works perfectly. Question: why doesn't the class nag for a corresponding table?

Comment: Calling the defined class method doesn't trigger any of the normal AR magic. It will most definitely complain if you try something like `ComplexQueries.new`.

Comment: One kvetch - as a rule, class names should be singular, so this so be either "ComplexQuery" or have some other indication of more specific purposes of the class.

Comment: Reference for the result of execute is available here: http://rubydoc.info/gems/mysql/2.8.1/Mysql/Result

Answer (score 7):

You can also grab the ActiveRecord connection and call [select_all](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#select_all):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all('select * from foo').each do |e|
  puts e.inspect
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create classes (models) that are not backing to a database you need to not state that they are inheriting from ActiveRecord.

Do

```
class RecentActivity
```

Instead of

```
class RecentActivity < ActiveRecord::Base
```

That being said, it still might be helpful to get some more information on what you are trying to do: for example if you want to have something like "comments" or "pictures" on multiple different things like an article, or someones profile or blogpost all within the same application, I'd recommend checking out [PolyMorphic Associations](http://guides.rails.info/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).

Comment: What I need is to execute the above query and instantiate some objects  with its content.