# Many to many table with an extra column in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, many-to-many

Is it possible to do this with only two Rails models, User and Event:

```
Users
|id        |name         |age         |
|1         |danilo       |26          |
|2         |joe          |23          |
|3         |carlos       |50          |
|4         |katy         |45          |

Events_Users
|event_id     |user_id        |confirmed       |
|1            |1              |1               |
|3            |3              |0               |
|4            |3              |1               |
|2            |3              |1               |

Events
|id           |name                     |date            |
|1            |the end of the year      |31/12/2012      |
|2            |the end of the world     |21/12/2012      |
|3            |Party                    |18/12/2012      |
|4            |Dinner                   |19/12/2012      |
```

The problem is, the user can confirm or not their presence in an
event, for this I used the table Events_Users, column confirmed (1 for
confirmed). How can I do this with Rails ActiveRecord without an model
"Event_User"? How can I manipulate the confirmed column in the User
model?

I am using Rails 3.2.9 .

Comment: Does this question solve yours? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285034/custom-sql-query-without-corresponding-table

Comment: I think the most elegant solution is the one you have. User has_many :events_users (I would rename Events_Users to "Confirmation") and an Event has_many :users, :through => confirmations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`User` and `Event` have `many-to-many` relationship, you can not set up this association with just 2 model, you must have the join model, or join table.

In your case, you added attribute `confirmed`, so you will need a join model, named **Confirmation** (as other people recommended). Your define associations will be like this:

```
class User
  has_many :events, through: :confirmations
  has_many :confirmations
end

class Event
  has_many :users, through: :confirmations
  has_many :confirmations
end

class Confirmation
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of use for the User model, with the relation

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :events
```

and modify the join table Events_Users (it's a bit dirty)

is better to use a model Confirmation with two **belongs_to** relations:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :event
```

I hope this can help you,
Alessandro

Comment: Thanks for the answer Alessandro! You are right but the Kien's answer is more complete. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the extra field on the join table you'll want a join model. Check this out:

```
class User
  has_many :invitations
  has_many :invited_events,   -> {where(confirmed: false)}, class_name: 'Event', through: :invitations
  has_many :confirmed_events, -> {where(confirmed: true)},  class_name: 'Event', through: :invitations
end

class Event
  has_many :invitations
  has_many :invited_users,   -> {where(confirmed: false)}, class_name: 'User', through: :invitations
  has_many :confirmed_users, -> {where(confirmed: true)},  class_name: 'User', through: :invitations
end

class Invitation
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
end
```

With this, `user.confirmed_events` will provide the user's events only where the confirmed flag is set to true in the join table.